# Setting up Apache Mahout to use MySql

Tags: java, mysql, mahout

I am a .NET developer by trade, but I am working on a REST service implementation of Mahout for our website. I am having trouble setting up Mysql as the DataSource for MySQLJDBCDataModel. This is essentially how I am trying to go about it (Yes it is copy and pasted from *Mahout In Action*.)

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource ();
dataSource.setServerName("my_database_host");
dataSource.setUser("my_user");
dataSource.setPassword("my_password");
dataSource.setDatabaseName("my_database_name");
JDBCDataModel dataModel = new MySQLJDBCDataModel(
dataSource, "my_prefs_table", "my_user_column",
"my_item_column", "my_pref_value_column");
```

The problem is that Java is not recognizing "MysqlDataSource" as a valid object and won't compile. When I try to include "com.mysql.*" it says it can't resolve that either.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your MySQL driver in the java classpath? See if [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/) here helps.
Next time, please post details of your setup, like which server hosts your app.

Comment: Yep, you definitely must add the MySQL Connector/J driver JAR to the project or this won't work.